# jQuery mouse Out call CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I Currently have a CSS3 animation for Mouse Hover Event, see it below:

```
#topo .menu-header ul li:hover a {
    -webkit-animation: menuanimate 0.3s linear 0s both;
    -moz-animation: menuanimate 0.3s linear 0s both;
    -o-animation: menuanimate 0.3s linear 0s both;
    -ms-animation: menuanimate 0.3s linear 0s both;
    animation: menuanimate 0.3s linear 0s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes menuanimate{
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg); /* Firefox */
        color: #353535; 
        background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: 3px 18px;
    }
    51% {
        transform: rotateY(270deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg); /* Firefox */
        color: #fff;
        background: #f15a25;
    }
    100% { 
        color: #fff; background: #f15a25;
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg); /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

The Problem is: When the user move the mouse away from the button, there is no Animation for that. in CSS there is no mouse out event, so, is there a way to call an animation of Mouse Out like that in jQuery?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just call it with jQuery like:

```
$('element').hover(function(e)
{
     $(this).css({"rollover animation css in here..."});
},function(e)
{
     $(this).css({"rolloff animation css in here..."});
});
```

or even just have 2 classes ".over" and ".out" and then use $(this).addClass("over") & same for out on rolloff?

Comment: Thanks for answering me! But for some reason, It doesn't worked with CSS3 Animate. Then i Found that jQuery Plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ and it worked really nice. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: you know you can do all of these without needing the css transitions right? cross-browser also (IE6 and up)

Comment: what? I didn't know that! Could you tell me more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: yep you can use the standard transform property in css (with fallbacks for -webkit- -o- -moz- -ms-) then for the old IE browsers you need to use filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(matrix values in here) if you attach this to the 'step' in jquery animate you get animated rotation, 3d etc etc. you just need a bit of math trigonometry and apply to the transform matrix. I made a jquery plugin once.. one day I'll get around to open sourcing it

Comment: theres a a guy here who gets close but doesnt address the IE thing http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/22/jquery-patch-css-transform.html  the big gotcha to overcome for the IE8/IE7/IE6 issue is you need to base translations at 0,0 coordinates via math trig in your transform matrix. you simply apply it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342002/get-the-dximagetransform-microsoft-matrix-value-from-javascript  but on a stepped interval

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Thanks for share your knowledge, it was very useful!